# bash complains file not found for existing sqlite3 executable

Tags: bash, sqlite

I get a strange file not found error when running precompiled `sqlite3` binary:

```
/tmp/sqlite> ./sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3 
bash: ./sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3: No such file or directory
```

But the file does exist:

```
/tmp/sqlite> ls -l ./sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 **** **** 1202884 Feb 22 19:19 ./sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3
```

I downloaded sqlite3 Precompiled Binaries for Linux listed at https://sqlite.org/download.html:

```
/tmp/sqlite> wget https://sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip
--2022-03-07 19:53:33--  https://sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip
Resolving sqlite.org (sqlite.org)... 45.33.6.223
Connecting to sqlite.org (sqlite.org)|45.33.6.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2231371 (2.1M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip’

sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip 100%[===============================================================>]   2.13M  2.25MB/s    in 0.9s    

2022-03-07 19:53:35 (2.25 MB/s) - ‘sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip’ saved [2231371/2231371]
/tmp/sqlite> unzip sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip 
Archive:  sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000.zip
   creating: sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/
  inflating: sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3  
  inflating: sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqlite3_analyzer  
  inflating: sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3380000/sqldiff
```

Not sure if I am making some very stupid mistake or is the `sqlite3` Linux executable is broken?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13391/108618

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski that was super quick

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was due to 64bit/32bit issue as per the comment by Kamil.